# I Wanted To Get Notified By Local Notification When My App Is In Background Or Else In Foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have a PrayerButton in my drawer menu, On tapping it goes to 
 PrayerViewController, and in PrayerViewController
 i have 5 Prayer Timings where i created a UI local notification method and fired those timings in firedate and sound too. now my query is.

1. where should i call my notification method.

“All i want is my local notification method should call when my app is in Background, foreground and it should continuously running like a service, so that whenever those 5 Prayer time will come on firedate then it should alert me by UI Local Notification banner (when in foreground) and if  app is in background it should notify me".

i am a beginner in Stackoverflow might be my way of asking question will not be right but i tried asking Question.

sorry for the mistakes

and welcome to any reply

thanks in advance..

Comment: You can schedule a local notification to display when your app is in the background and you can have this notification repeat at the same time daily or weekly. When your app is in the foreground you can handle the notification via the `didReceiveLocalNotification` application delegate method. When your app is in the background you don't receive any notification to your code unless the user taps the notification banner

Comment: @Paulw11 http://imgur.com/a/6EObg   please have a look on this link , i have uploaded few images to explain it clearly.

Comment: @Paulw11 1st image:- i have written a method in ViewController.m  2. i have declared in ViewController.h 3. Called that method in didReceiveLocalNotification in App delegate.  am i going right?

Answer (score -1):

Use these app delegate methods

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```